# DateFormat.getTimeInstance doesn't format the correct locale

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat, time-format

I'm trying to get the `time` from a given `Date` and format it properly to a certain `Locale`.
I've been using `DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale).format(date)` and it works on my emulator, but doesn't work on my phone.

I set the locale to `en_US` and I change the `Language & Input` on my phone to `Swedish`. Then, when I try to get the `time` I get it in `24 hour` format even though I try to format it with an `en_US` locale. If I try the same thing on my emulator, there's no problem, the `time` is properly formatted.

**Emulator**
`Date - Tue Feb 05 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019`
`time - 12:00 AM`

**Phone**
`Date - Tue Feb 05 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019`
`time - 00:00`

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `DateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Are you saying that the phone uses the phone’s locale setting for formatting no matter which locale you are passing to `getTimeInstance`? Or is it rather that the phone has a different idea of what en_US time formatting should look like??

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah, the phone uses the phone's locale for formatting no matter which locale I am passing.